# Write activerecord query in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I am having "Order" model with pickup_date, delivery_date and status.
So i want to select orders -

- if status if picked_up then pickup_date should be some date value `(eg, '12/12/2012')`
- if status if delivered then delivery_date should be some date value `(eg, '12/12/2012')`

I think we can use `WHEN CASE` with Activerecord. Can anybody help me in this?

Answer (score 1):

```
Order.where("(status = 'pickup_up' AND pickup_date = :date) OR (status = 'delivered' AND delivery_date = :date)", date: Date.today)
```

In Rails 5 you can actually already use 'or' method for ActiveRecord relations:

```
Order.where(status: :picked_up, pickup_date: Date.today).or(Order.where(status: :delivered, delivery_date: Date.today))
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @M. Stavnycha answer, Rails has a great section on ActiveRecord query interface available here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Order.where(status: :picked_up).update(:pickup_date '12/12/2012')

Order.where(status: :delivered).update(:delivery_date '12/12/2012')
```